# TikZ: trouble with node placement when I want to reference from a point other than the origin

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every label/.append style = {font = \scriptsize},
dot/.style = {inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle,
  draw = black, label = {#1}},
small dot/.style = {minimum size = .05cm, dot = {#1}},
big dot/.style = {minimum size = .1cm, dot = {#1}},
]
\node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(F\)}] (F) at (2, 0) {};
\node[fill = black, big dot = {above left: \(A\)}] (A) at (2, 0) -- ++({2 * cos(45)}, {3 * sin(45)}) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want my node to be 45 degrees from the point `(2, 0)` and not the origin.  How can I do this?

With Jakes comment, the node is placed correctly but the dot isn't the correct size.

```
 \path (2, 0) -- ++({2 * cos(45)}, {3 * sin(45)})
 node[fill = black, big dot = {above right: \(A\)}] (A) {x};
```

[image]

By removing the `{x}` as suggested by Qrrbrbirlbel, Jakes comment worked perfectly.

```
 \path (2, 0) -- ++({2 * cos(45)}, {3 * sin(45)})
 node[fill = black, big dot = {above right: \(A\)}] (A) {};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `shift` option inside the coordinate options, this is the same as adding the coordinates.

Instead of `({2 * cos(45)}, {3 * sin(45)})`, I have also used a polar coordinate: `(45:3 and 2)`. The space after the *x* radius is mandatory so if you have the radii saved in a macro, you need to do `(45:{\xr} and \yr)` or `(45:\xr\space and \yr)`.

There is no difference between

```
([shift=(F)] 45:3 and 2)
```

and

```
([shift=(45:3 and 2)] F)
```

If you want to place a bunch of nodes relatively to `F`, you might use a `scope`:

```
\begin{scope}[shift=(F)]
     % many \nodes
\end{scope}
```

or—as in my example—you specify the shift as an option to the path (remember that `\node` simply expands to `\path node`):

```
\path[shift=(F)] \foreach \Angle in {90,135,...,360} {
                                    node[big dot={\Angle:\Angle}] at (\Angle:3 and 2) {}};
```

---

If you load the `calc` library, you also have the possibility to do

```
($(F)+(45:3 and 2)$)
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every label/.append style = {font = \scriptsize},
  dot/.style = {inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle,
    draw = black, label = {#1}},
  small dot/.style = {minimum size = .05cm, dot = {#1}},
  big dot/.style = {minimum size = .1cm, dot = {#1}},
]
\node[fill = blue,  big dot = {below:      \(O\)}] (O) at (0,0) {};
\node[fill = black, big dot = {below left: \(F\)}] (F) at (2, 0) {};
\node[fill = black, big dot = {above left: \(A\)}] (A) at ([shift=(F)] 45:3 and 2) {};
\path[shift=(F)] \foreach \Angle in {90,135,...,360} {
                                    node[big dot={\Angle:\Angle}] at (\Angle:3 and 2) {}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Can you add in Jake's answer with your suggestion of removing the `{x}`?  I only ask because that is what I used but Jake deleted his comments and didn't pose a solution.