# TikZ: node placement when using draw let in syntax

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

When using the `\draw let ... in` syntax to construct an arc between 2 lines, the arc is placed in the correct location even if the arc's focal point isn't the origin.  However, this isn't the case with the node placement.

For example, consider this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (F) at (2, 0);

  \draw (F) -- ++(30:1cm and 2cm) coordinate (A);
  \draw (F) -- ++(100:1cm) coordinate (P3);

  \draw let
      \p0 = (F),
      \p1 = (A),
      \p2 = (P3),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {1cm},
      \n4 = {(\n2 - \n1) / 2}
    in (F) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[scale = .75, fill = white, inner sep = 0cm] at
    (\n4:\n3) {\(\nu_A\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

If I `xshift = 2` the node, I get:

[image]

I don't understand why the node placement isn't along the arc since I specified the placement at `(\n4:\n3)` which is half the arc angle with the same radius.  That is, it should be along the arc equidistant from both lines.

If add to the node options `pos = .5`, the node is still not placed where one would anticipate.

[image]

What is the correct nodal syntax for this situation with `\draw let .. in`?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to do this?   `\draw let
      \p0 = (F),
      \p1 = (A),
      \p2 = (P3),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {1cm},
      \n4 = {(\n2 + \n1) / 2}
    in (F) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[fill = white, inner sep = 0cm,xshift=2cm,font=\small] at
    (\n4:\n3) {\(\nu_A\)};`. The `scale` option in your code affects shifting; it's better to use `font=` to change the font (if that was your intent in the first place).

Comment: Nodes do not work very good along of `arc`s, see [How to place a node in the middle of an arc?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38763). The coordinate `(\n4:\n3)` is relative to the origin of the coordinate system, not the center of the arc, you will need to use `at ([shift=(F)] \n4:\n3)` or `(F)+(\n4:\n3) node …` (while `\n4 = {(\n2 + \n1) / 2}` of course).

Comment: @dustin if `scale` is used before the shifting, then the shifting also gets scaled. If `scale` is used after the shifting, then the shifting is not scaled.

Comment: I don't know; perhaps @Qrrbrbirlbel is writing an answer already? If not, I'll do it.

Comment: @dustin using my `xshift=2cm` and his `shift=(F)` are basically the same (but I prefer his solution).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina To be honest, I also prefer my solution since it uses the already defined coordinate which is already available and known to TikZ while `xshift` only works for the canvas plane. @dustin Though, Gonzalo’s is absolutely right about the `scale` vs `font` issue.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel yes. Please, go ahead and write your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately and as already discussed in [How to place a node in the middle of an arc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38763/16595) nodes cannot placed along `arc`s. So simply using no `at` and adding `pos=.5` (or any other position for that matter) will place the node at the origin, TikZ just doesn’t know better.

Then there are two problems in your code: Firstly you define `\n4` as the half of `\n2 - \n1`, though the angle bisector is `.5*(\n2+\n1)`.
Then, the node is placed `at (\n4:\n3)` which is an absolute coordinate is not taken in any relation to the center of the arc `(F)`. We could use `at +(\n4:\n3)` here, but the last coordinate from which the relative coordinate is located is the end of the `arc`, but not still `(F)`.

We need to use `at ([shift=(F)] \n4:\n3)` or `(F) +(\n4:\n3) node …` here (→ [TikZ: trouble with node placement when I want to reference from a point other than the origin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122776/16595)).

As already commented by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123038/tikz-node-placement-when-using-draw-let-in-syntax?noredirect=1#comment275288_123038) it is always better to use `font` to change the font-size of the nodes text instead of the `scale` option.

You are also already familiar with the `decorations.markings` library which might be preferable in different cases.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (F) at (2, 0);

  \draw (F) -- ++(30:1cm and 2cm) coordinate (A);
  \draw (F) -- ++(100:1cm) coordinate (P3);

  \draw let
      \p0 = (F),
      \p1 = (A),
      \p2 = (P3),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {1cm},
      \n4 = {(\n2 + \n1) / 2}
    in (F) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[fill = white, inner sep = 0cm, font=\small] at ([shift=(F)] \n4:\n3) {\(\nu_A\)}
%    [decoration={name=markings,mark=at position .5 with {\node [inner sep=+0cm,font=\small,fill=white] {$\nu_A$};}},postaction=decorate]
   ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]